# after insert trigger does not work when insert happens from node js app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, triggers

I have a after insert trigger. that calls a stored procedure .when I run a direct query it works well. but when I insert  data through node js app . it does not even insert data in main table . There is not any error in trigger and stored procedure cause it works with direct insert query for the table .

```
dbObject.create(data, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            //console.log("err", err);
            res.status(500).jsonp(response)
        }
        console.log("response", response);
        dbObject.find({SnsId: SnsId}, '*' , {}, 0, 0, {}, function(err, resp){
            if (err) {
                //console.log("err", err);
                res.status(500).jsonp(err)
            }
            console.log("response", resp);
            res.jsonp(resp);
        });
    });
```

trigger code --

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `copytoSensorMapTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON test4.`SENSORS`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   CALL copyToSensorMap(NEW.`SnsId`,NEW.`SnsState`);
END;
```

Stored Procedure code --

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE copyToSensorMap(IN snsid bigint(20),IN sns_state varchar(128))
   BEGIN
   DECLARE  color varchar(128);
   INSERT INTO test3.`SENSOR_MAP` (`SENSOR_ID`, `SENSOR_NAME`, `USER_ID`, `HOST_ID`,  `SENSOR_STATE`)
    SELECT `SnsId`,
   `SnsName`,`SnsOwner`,`HostId`,`SnsState`
         FROM test4.`SENSORS`
         where test4.`SENSORS`.`SnsId`=snsid;
    IF ( sns_state ='Unassigned') THEN
        set color = 'Grey';
    ELSEIF ( sns_state ='Running') THEN
     set color = 'Green';
    END IF;
    update test3.`SENSOR_MAP`
       set test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.`SENSOR_COLOR` = color
       where test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.`SENSOR_ID` = snsid;
UPDATE test3.`SENSOR_MAP`
  INNER JOIN test4.`HOSTS`
    ON (test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.`HOST_ID` = test4.`HOSTS`.id)
  SET 
    test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.HOST_NAME = test4.HOSTS.Name,
    test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.LATITUDE = test4.HOSTS.GpsLatitude,
    test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.LONGITUDE = test4.HOSTS.GpsLongitude;
UPDATE test3.`SENSOR_MAP`
  INNER JOIN test4.`users` ON (test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.`USER_ID` = test4.`users`.id)
  SET 
    test3.`SENSOR_MAP`.USER_NAME = test4.users.user;
UPDATE  test3.`SENSOR_MAP`  c
    INNER JOIN
    (
        select a.`SnsId`,b.id,b.ServiceName,b.ServiceType
           from test4.sensors as a
           join test4.SESSIONS as b  on a.SessionId =b.id
           where a.`SnsId` =snsid
           group by `SnsId` 
    ) d  ON c.SENSOR_ID = d.`SnsId`
    SET c.SESSION_NAME = d.ServiceName,
        c.SESSION_TYPE = d.ServiceType;
END $$
```

I am using Mysql database and storage engine is InnoDB. I have checked the sql query . it is forming with SET Keyword.
does Mysql insert query with set keyword support after insert stored procedure.

Issue is solved now. it was a table name in all caps in Mysql and I had written in lowercase.tables names were "user" and "sensor" . now it is solved.

Comment: Not much that can be inferred from that piece of code, try to post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You might try logging the actual SQL query used when you call `dbObject.create(...)` and comparing that to what you're doing manually to see if there's any discrepancy

Comment: "it does not even insert data in main table"- that means the issue is in your node.js database insert. It is not possible to identify the issue with the code snippet that you shared. Please specify which db you are using and more code snippet corresponding to it.

Comment: updated database information in question.

Comment: Is it an idea to let your nodeJS app talk to an API? That way you have a little more control about how and by which method your queries are executed.

Comment: does Mysql insert query with set keyword support after insert stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend to use `return` in the places you check for errors, otherwise the code will continue and not stop in case of errors.

Try using this code:

```
dbObject.create(data, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        //console.log("err", err);
        return res.status(500).jsonp(response)
    }
    console.log("response", response);
    dbObject.find({SnsId: SnsId}, '*' , {}, 0, 0, {}, function(err, resp){
        if (err) {
            //console.log("err", err);
            return res.status(500).jsonp(err)
        }
        console.log("response", resp);
        res.jsonp(resp);
    });
});
```

Comment: @miken32 Umm, he edited his original question to add the return statements after this was posted.

Comment: Haha, sorry about that. Still doesn't answer the question.